# upgrade gradle version from 4.3 to 4.4 using command promt windows

Tags: react-native, gradle

I am working on a react-native project. 
when I run gradle clean command I get an error regarding gradle version.
My computer has gradle version 4.3.1 and I want to upgrade it to version 4.4.
I don't have android studio installed so i want to update the gradle from my command prompt only. 
Is there any where to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If your project works with the gradle wrapper you can update the wrapper with the command:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.4 --distribution-type=bin
```

But I guess your project doesn't use the wrapper, otherwise you wouldn't need to have a gradle version installed. This page may help then: https://gradle.org/install/